# Using Razor Templates Stored in Razor Class Library 3.0 (RCL) Without AspNetCore Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core, razor-class-library

I am using Razor templates (cshtml) to build HTML for use in emails. While I can get this all to work and I can send email from a ASPNetCore 3.0 web application I want to actually send email from another process which is NOT a web application. Ideally I would like to queue email, which can be triggered from any number of backend processes, and then send those from a timer like service which runs as a windows service or possibly a back-end worker running in Azure via something like Functions.

Is there any way to leverage razor templates from within a RCL in a .NetCore console or other application which is NOT hosted in AspNetCore??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there isn't a way to do this i am sry. :(

Comment: Thanks for the fast agreement.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use [RazorEngine](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorEngine/), which I used in .NET Framework 4.6.2 Class Library. There is a [.Net Core Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorEngine.NetCore/) as well.

I referenced such Class Library projects from Console Applications, Windows Services and Azure Cloud Services (Worker Roles).

In my setup, I had to mark Razor files as Content so they are copied over to the bin folder. Also, it got more complicated if library is referenced by another library and then that library is used; content did not get copied over or it got flattened out (all razor views ended up in the root of the bin folder vs following directory structures), for which there is a fix by editing project file and adding your own copy build tasks. Or I had to embed razor views into DLL.

There might be improvements to this in recent years, as I said I used RazorEngine few years back. And it might be different in .Net Core RCL as well, but I believe it is possible.

Nowadays, I am using 3rd party services like SendGrid or MailJet. For me, using them avoids majority of the above issues and offers better insight into emails/templates/campaigns to Marketing and other non-tech users. They can edit and modify templates to their liking without (m)any code deployments.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the code through ASP.net core engine so that  Razor code get converted into html.
Otherwise use simple html template.